# Wordpress All-in-one Event calendar custom template include css and js files in header

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have inherited a wordpress project from a designer that built a static html/css/js website and have been tasked with creating a wordpress template out of it from scratch.

I am just about at the end of the project and I have run into a weird(or perfectly normal) issue where the javascript for the all in one calendar plugin works on a sub page but does not work on the static home page.

if i remove wp_head(); i lose all the styling/js for the all in one calendar.

Wordpress Header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>TriNimbus</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="TriNimbus">
    <meta name="author" content="op">
    <?php
    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
    ?>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fonts/font.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js">    </script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <header class="general-header">
        <div class="center">
            <h1>
                <a href="/"></a>
                <object class="logo" data="<?php   bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.svg"></object>
            </h1>
            <nav>
                <i id="menu-bars" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' =>   'header-menu')); ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

[WordPress All In One Calendar Plugin Time.ly events page](http://trinimbus.staging.wpengine.com/events/)

The above works as expected the dropdowns work etc etc.

[WordPress All in One Calendar Home Page with Issue](http://trinimbus.staging.wpengine.com/)

The above loads but NONE of the javascript works properly.

both use  to render the plugin

It seems like a javascript or jquery conflict but I'm not sure what to do in order to track down what the actual issue is.

Can someone please help me with some ideas on what I can do to trouble shoot this issues.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: better try on this [dedicated site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks  ramabarca tried as suggested